# Correct behavior of shouldChangeCharactersIn method, the delegate of UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfielddelegate

There two UITextField (email, password) in the Login/SIgnup controllers in my code (here is the [example](https://github.com/AdAvAn/ShouldChangeCharactersInRange)), so that users obviously could insert login/password to register/log in.

In the method `shouldChangeCharactersIn` I check the data inserted by user and afterwards execute method `loginButtonChangeState()`, that activates the login button, in case data inserted are correct:

1. Email: should be an email, checked with RegEx.
2. Password: Should be at least 6 characters in length

Here is the content of the method:

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if let text = textField.text,
            let textRange = Range(range, in: text) {
            let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)

            switch textField {
                case _ where textField.isIdentical(with: email) : state[textField] = chekMail(for: updatedText)
                case _ where textField.isIdentical(with: password) : state[textField] = chekPass(for: updatedText)
                default: break
            }

             loginButtonChangeState()

            print("shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:\(text), replacementString: \(string)")
        }
        return true
    }
```

This code works well, but the following sequence of actions breaks it, and login button keeps active.

1. Enter Email , e.g. t@t.com
2. Than enter password, e.g. 123456
3. Login button – becomes active
4. tap/go to the address field again
5. tap/go back to the password field
6. tap on the keyboard backspace button à login button keeps active though it should have become inactive.

The reason, why it keeps active, is because after taping backspace `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method transfers old content of the `UITextField`, which can be seen in the console log

```
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:, replacementString: t
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t, replacementString: @
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t@, replacementString: t
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t@t, replacementString: .
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t@t., replacementString: c
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t@t.c, replacementString: o
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:t@t.co, replacementString: m
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:, replacementString: 1
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:1, replacementString: 2
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:12, replacementString: 3
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:123, replacementString: 4
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:1234, replacementString: 5
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:12345, replacementString: 6
shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:123456, replacementString:
```

In this row "**shouldChangeCharactersIn: textField.text:123456, replacementString:** " it is seen, that `replacementString` is "*space sighn*", but `textField.text` still contains "*123456*".

Video can be seen here: https://github.com/AdAvAn/ShouldChangeCharactersInRange/raw/master/shouldChangeCharactersIn.gif

**QUESTION:**

How can I correct the work of the method so that “Log In” button become inactive after taping backspace on keyboard (*Ideally without clearing the content of the password UITextField)*?

> UDP: 25.03.18

This problem only occurs for fields that have the `isSecureTextEntry` parameter true.

So far I have not found a more beautiful solution, except to set `password.clearsOnBeginEditing = true`. This allows you to clear the contents of the password field each time it triggers func `textFieldDidBeginEditing (_ textField: UITextField)`.

Comment: Could you just try replacing your logic with `let existingText = textField.text as NSString? let changedText = existingText?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)`

Comment: The problem is that at the moment of pressing the space textField.text contains the previous value. Your code will simply add a space to the end of the line. In my method there is its analog.
let textRange = Range (range, in: text) {
             let updatedText = text.replacingCharacters (in: textRange, with: string)

Answer (score 5):

There is not much I did, just removed some of your lines. The updatedText should now reflect the current text of the textfield correctly, no matter whether you delete a character or add one. If your code still does not work then you got to check your switch statement and check methods.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let previousText:NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    let updatedText = previousText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    print("updatedText > ", updatedText)

   //the rest of your code

    return true
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added your code to my test project (https://github.com/AdAvAn/ShouldChangeCharactersInRange), the result did not change :(.
updatedText> 1
updatedText> 12
updatedText> 123
updatedText> 1234
updatedText> 12345
updatedText> 123456
updatedText> 123456

Comment: Thank you, it helps me alot

Comment: @BCI Thanks and upvote this is what I am looking for